# Pandas - Merge/Lookup 2 dataframes based on certain column as an index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say that I have 2 dataframe (**df1** & **df2**)

**df1**

```
DF1 = ID     Name     Age
      A     Bob       20
      B     James     23
      C     Felicia   33
      D     John      21
      B     Anita     41


DF2 = ID     Education       Title
      A      Junior High     Junior
      B      Senior High     Senior
      C      College         Bachelor
      D      University      Master
```

I want to merge/join/lookup/map (I don't know what I should use) so it will produce a **df3** like this:

```
DF = ID     Name     Age     Education         Title
      A     Bob       20     Junior High       Junior
      B     James     23     Senior High       Senior
      C     Felicia   33     College           Bachelor
      D     John      21     University        Master
      B     Anita     41     Senior High       Senior
```

As you can see, I use 'ID' column as the index.
How do I merge these 2 dataframes? I know the example data doesn't make sense but let's not focus on that!

Comment: df3= pd.merge(df1,df2, on='ID')

Comment: on my particular df, this syntax caused ‘You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns’. When i convert the data type using astype it doesn't work

Comment: before merging, reset the index using df.reset_index(), then just check the datatypes of ID column. if it same then you can merge. if its different, then you need to type cast.